# Is spline cage modeling technique in blender possible?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, bezier-curves, workflow

I saw this technique for modeling cars in Cinema 4D and I wonder if it is possible to achieve in blender. I tried to snap meshes to curves in blender but it doesn't seem to work

here is the video showing the method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=blWQ3GXPkHc&t=1s .  At 11:03, he starts snapping quads onto splines.

Also here is a picture of the "Spline cage" : [image]

Comment: Not everyone here uses Cinema 4D or knows what spline cage modeling is. Could you explain how it works, and also make your link clickable?

Comment: I looked at your link long enough to see that it was 37 minutes long.  Can you provide a timestamp for the technique you're talking about?

Comment: @Nathan you can see at 11:03 he started snapping quads onto the splines that he made initially.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos
 I have made the link clickable. The technique shown is to initially outline the shape of the vehicle based on the blueprints using splines. Then, he starts snapping polygons to these curves in order to create the mesh. The advantage here is that the spline cage is kind of like a sketch but 3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From what I can tell from the video:*

Assuming you already know how to build a 3D wireframe from reference images, all that's left is to quickly extrude edges of a mesh and snap its vertices to the wireframe. Two ways I can think of doing that:

**1. Poly Build tool**

The native Poly Build tool in *Edit Mode* lets you create edge extrusions and snap vertices with just the left mouse button. Here's [a short Blender Secrets video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oO6o1O6yV6E) to demonstrate its use. You should, of course, make sure you have appropriate snapping options turned on in the *Snap menu* (you can hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select multiple options:

[image]

[image]

**2. Tweak tool with Vertex + Edge mode**

*Poly Build* is a more dedicated tool for retopology, but if you wanted, you could come pretty close to it with the *Tweak* tool as well. Just have both the *Vertex* (<kbd>1</kbd>) and the *Edge* selection (<kbd>2</kbd>) modes enabled along with the appropriate snapping options. The main difference with *Poly Build* would be the fact that you need to press <kbd>E</kbd> everytime to extrude an edge instead of simply clicking-and-dragging them.

[image]

**Note:** If your wireframe has curvy-curves you can't seem to snap to, you might wanna make a copy of it, then *Right Click menu > Convert to > Mesh*—now you should be able to snap to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation ! , could you further elaborate on how can I create the 3d wireframe in blender ? , is it using NURBS or what ?

Comment: @Abdul You would use the same method you see in your video. Set up your reference images, then trace over it by extruding vertices and edges of a mesh (or curve). There are many, many tutorials you can find if you google "blender model from reference" etc. Here's an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3wQeoXYuuY

Comment: Thanks so much that was quite helpful